# How to get all the data from the database and display in a table

Tags: python, mysql, angularjs, django

Hi am working on a python-django(v1.6) project and I need to come up with a table, which contains the data from my database. I have already my templeteview and template ready. 
my view

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    model = Mymodel
    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['ngapp'] = "Myapp"
        return context

    def get_data(request):
        query_results = Mymodel.objects.objects.all()
```

my html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

<!--Page heading-->
{% block page_title %}My home{% endblock %}
<!---->

{% block content %}
<div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        {% for item in query_results %}
            <tr>
                <td> {{ item.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>


</div>
{% endblock %}
```

As per my code, no idea why the name is not displaying. How can I get the data(specific column) from my DB and display that in a table? Using AngularJS a better way? Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Please try working something out, and come back if you got issues with your code.

Comment: dendimiiii: forgot to include my views part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing your queryset to your template. Try like this:

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    model = Mymodel
    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['ngapp'] = "Myapp"
        context['query_results'] = self.get_data()
        return context

    def get_data(self):
        query_results = self.model.objects.all()
        return query_results
```

Comment: It worked when i put a print statement in my views. But didnt worked in my template. I just put {{ query_results }} inside my div. But it returned None and its affected my loop also

Comment: Yeah. Missed the return type

Answer (score 0):

Reading up on Django Querysets should help you here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/

Passing the queryset to your template in the render function and iterating over it in the template will display all your data.